# Sort by main domain

Tags: php

I got a list of website url's like this:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.another.com/1/hi-hello
http://www.example.com/index.php
http://www.another.com/1/archive
http://www.example.com/about.php
http://www.another.com/
```

and so on... All in random order.

Now what I want is to sort this list by main-domain names like this:

```
http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/index.php
- http://www.example.com/about.php

http://www.another.com/
- http://www.another.com/1/hi-hello
- http://www.another.com/1/archive
```

So can anyone point me in the right direction how to detect the main domain and list the others? I was thinking about a RegEx but as it can be any domain it's quite a big job to recognize...

Comment: What's a "main domain"? If you invent terms you must define them :)

Comment: Look at the example given.... @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: One example is not sufficient to form a rigourous definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy with [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/function.parse-url):

```
<?php
$urls = Array(
    "http://www.example.com/",
    "http://www.another.com/1/hi-hello",
    "http://www.example.com/index.php",
    "http://www.another.com/1/archive",
    "http://www.example.com/about.php",
    "http://www.another.com/"
);

$urls_categorised = Array();

// First, group all the array elements by HOST
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($url != $host)
        $urls_categorised[$host][] = $url;
}

// Now render each category in the way you specified
foreach ($urls_categorised as &$x) {
    if (!count($x))
        continue;

    sort($x);
    print "{$x[0]}\n";
    array_shift($x);

    foreach ($x as $y)
        print "- {$y}\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/about.php
- http://www.example.com/index.php
http://www.another.com/
- http://www.another.com/1/archive
- http://www.another.com/1/hi-hello
```

### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/ak4DEH)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, the idea of creating a new array is awesome.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting: A custom sort function would be another option that avoids the doubling up of storage requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parse_url() function to get the host from the urls you have. Then, you will be able to separate your results the good way.

Comment: I think he means "the way you want"

Comment: I meant to say "the way you want it to be separated", my bad if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

what i would do is add them to an array. create a loop to check each of the items and explode each array item. that way you can search the array term and do a second loop to pull out only those who match the search query
something like this?

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
foreach ($array as $value)
  {
  foreach ($array as $value2)
  {
  if ($value == $value2) echo "- " . $value2;
  }
  }
```

you would have to explode the $value and $value2 of course in able to get the domain name